# Date bars are too sticky

Tags: food-science, texture, mixing

I am making date bars very similar to nakd bars but keeping running into the same problem when making them.

The bars are way too sticky!

I used the following ingredients

- Dates
- Freeze dried raspberries
- Salt
- Vanilla extract

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? the taste is there but the texture is not.

The Nakd bars have a harder feel to them but I'm not sure how to get that. Ingredients and measurements are very similar too.

Comment: Welcome to the site, you will need to edit and add the amounts of these ingredients and the detailed method you use to make the bars.

Comment: maybe the humidity level of the dates is too high ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as needing detail. This question is the equivalent of saying 'I mixed flour, water, yeast and salt together and my bread isn't coming out right, what am I doing wrong?'